# where to solder antenna on 433 MHz remote control

Tags: pcb, antenna, 433mhz, remote

I would like to install this remote into a carbon component, which apparently shields all rf signals.

So, I need to solder an external antenna to this remote control pcb, but I could not figure out where to. it is a standard cheap remote, you can find on aliexpress with the a022 name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Identify the antenna. It may be the track on both layers around the curved edge. Cut (on both layers) at the amplifier end and attach your antenna. You may have to sacrifice a remote or two if it doesn't work (with decent range) first time.

Comment: ... or, don't buy a device off Aliexpress that doesn't come without documentation if you need to integrate it into something.

Comment: ... and are unable to reverse engineer this yourself. The circuit isn't complex, do your research on 433 MHz transmit circuits and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the device wasn't buyed especially for this integration, it just was at hand. the original remote for this application was damaged, and i needed a quick replacment.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, complex is subjective: maybe for an electronics engineer it is not complex, but for a beginner hobbyist it could be! plus, those smd components are not easy to identify. i tried to search for 433mhz remote controller schematics, but didn't find anything for this model.

Comment: @WanekT Cheap undocumented crap is much harder to work with than proper evaluation boards from well-known manufacturers. Reverse-engineering undocumented radio circuits is indeed not easy for a hobbyist... so why do you do it? Why not buy a PCB with a schematic and an antenna connector? Btw if you solder an external antenna to this, all radio certification goes null and void. You might end up with something that is illegal to use in the country where you live.

Comment: @Lundin, if you mind to read my previous posts, i explained that i needed a QUICK solution to replace an existing remote into a device. while finding / buying a dedicated evaluation board is indeed a nice idea, but can take several days / weeks to get the proper product. waiting several days wasn't an option in my case. this is why i opted for hacking a remote which i had at hand. by the way, if you can post some links about the evaluation boards you mentioned, it could be helpful in the future for other users too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the antenna is on top of the board as shown. It is the land on the outter left hand curved edge. It is also mirrored and connected with vias to the bottom. It is connected by a capacitor and has two holes drilled in it and further down in the middle, has 3 holes. The photo darkens at the bottom so it is hard to see if it ends in space or connects to something. On the top of the board, cut the land with maybe an exacto knife just before the two holes by the capacitor and solder an equivalent length wire (or 2X, 3X etc) by the capacitor. That's my best guess from what I see. If it doesn't do the job you can scrape the surface clean on the land and resolder it bridging the gap.

Comment: thanks for all the useful answers / comments! indeed, i managed to scrape the surface and solder a wire to the curved track. cutting the track didn't worked, because the other end of the antenna is also connected to some components (in the darker area of the photo you mention). so, i just soldered the wire and leave the track uncut. it works now, thanks!